# Regular Expression to limit consecutive capitalization

Tags: regex

I need to validate an input so that no "individual" word within the textbox can contain more than 3 consecutive capital letters. The following doesn't seem to be working:

```
[A-Z]{3,}
```

This is a VB application.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have an example of it not working?

Comment: The regex looks fine, but you said "more than 3", so shouldn't it be [A-Z]{4,}

Comment: I think I have my concept backwards.. because it fires when lowercase is entered. It should validate ONLY if the expression returns false. So how would I re-write this so dictate that?

Comment: btw - forgive me. Regex is still not my friend. I can't seem to get my head around it no matter how much I read. Sad...

Comment: Is this vbscript or what?

Comment: It's an application layer for a VB back-end. This is web-based... and the regex is supposed to be a standard type.

Comment: I am asking I suppose are you using re.Test for your regex?

Comment: @hwnd I'm not really sure, as I'm not working directly in VB. It's an application web-layer that sends it to code-behind. All I know is I can add a validate property to a text box. <validate target="mytexbox" type="regex" expression="Myexpression" />

Comment: But right now if I type in lowercase characters it's triggering the expression as in, (Sorry, can't do that.)... So apparently I need the opposite of my example.

Answer (score 2):

this pattern should do it `^(?!.*[A-Z]{4}).*`
a negative lookahead that does not see 4 consecutive upper case letters